# In java 1.5 : Can implemented run() method of java.lang.Runnable interface have a return type other than void?

Tags: java, multithreading

I appeared for an Interview today . the interviewer asked me to write a thread in java 1.5 
.Either you can extend java.lang.thread class or implement java.lang.Runnable interface.
Is it possible that implemented run() method have a return type other than void.
The method signature in Runnable interface is

```
public void run();
```

My answer was "you can not return an int or string from a run() method because of above signature definition."

the interviewer said in java 1.5 you can return int or string from run method.

can you all please tell me how it can be done ?

I tried below it gave compilation error :

```
public class SampleInterview implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public int run() {
        System.out.println("Start : inside run of SampleInterview");
        System.out.println("End : inside run of SampleInterview");
    }
}
```

I have searched google also could not find any such way. Is it possible or not ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible; either you misunderstood the interviewer, or they were wrong.  (You *might* just "write the return value into some shared variable," but that doesn't seem like it meets the requirements.)

The `Callable` interface, though, lets you return a value.

Comment: i too suggested to use shared object , but he said we want thread to return.

Answer (score 1):

I think the interviewer was referring to the `Callable` interface introduced in Java 1.5:

https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6

Which means that his question is not accurate since he is talking about Runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)

The run method has only void return type and that is since 1.4.2 specs.

So, your answer is correct, may be your interviewer is trying to twist you.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible, you were right..................

`run() method will never return anything`.

That was the problem with the threads,

```
cannot have a return type, and cant throw an exception.
```

Though java 7 has handled these issues in its

```
java.util.Concurrent package
```